# Fetch ldap password of all users as an administrator

Tags: openldap

I am a system administrator of one ldap server.

As a sys amdin my aim is to inform all the users their uid's and password stored ldap directory. I am able to get the uid's of all the user, but I am not able to fetch the password for individual user.

Essentially, I want to query ldap server to get the password details of each user.
I am not able to find the solution for this.

Please share how can I achieve this.

Comment: Passwords are generally stored in one way hashes and are not retrievable in clear text so in general this is not possible. Nor is it advisable.  Did all of the users forget their passwords?

Comment: I need to mail to the email-ids of all the users in ldap directory.
Many users might have forgotten their credentials, so I was planning to give them their both login id and password in the mail. I fetched uid's from ldap. But not password is not possible.

So the scenario or situation is like this.

Other solution is to reset all the user password using a random password generator library in python. And send the details to individual user.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Everything about this is totally insecure. You should tell them to use the password reset feature of your application, and if you don't have one, get one.